# what is the divisor is equal to zero in plsql?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

```
SELECT pstartdate, 
       opbal, 
       joined, 
       resign, 
       ( opbal + joined - resign ) clbal 
       , 
       ( Round(( ( resign * 100 ) / ( opbal + joined ) ) / 100, 2) * 100 
       ) attriation 
FROM   (SELECT pstartdate, 
               penddate, 
               Getopempbal(pstartdate)         OpBal, 
               Getempjn(pstartdate, penddate)  Joined, 
               Getempres(pstartdate, penddate) Resign 
        FROM   (SELECT Add_months(:startdate, LEVEL - 1) pstartdate, 
                       Add_months(:startdate, LEVEL) - 1 penddate 
                FROM   dual 
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= Months_between( :enddate, :startdate ) + 1)) 
ORDER  BY To_number(1)
```

When i executed this query Error came

> divisor is equal to zero.

i think error this place

`(round(((resign*100)/(opbal+joined))/100,2)*100) attriation`

Comment: the error is saying you can't divide by 0.  that means opbal+joined = 0

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Format properly. When you edit, mark the code and click `{}`.

Comment: What should be the result when `opbal+joined` = 0?

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but why are you ordering by `to_number(1)`? That will just evaluate to the constant `1`, which isn't going to affect the result set order anyway. I wondered if you were trying for a column reference, as shorthand for `to_number(pstartdate)`, but that would mean that date value would be stored in a weird format... maybe you really just meant to `order by 1` to get the results in date order?

Comment: A [zero divide error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero) is exactly the same in PL/SQL as it is in any other programming language.

Comment: Does this have **anything** to do with PL/SQL, or is it plain Oracle SQL? I don't see any PL/SQL anywhere (other than in the title and tag).

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that you use the `nullif()` function when doing division:

```
select . . .
       ( Round(( ( resign * 100 ) / nullif( opbal + joined, 0 ) ) / 100, 2) * 100 
       ) attriation
```

This returns `NULL` if the denominator is zero.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT pstartdate,
       opbal,
       joined,
       resign,
       (opbal+joined-resign) clbal,
       round((**NULLIF**(resign,0) *100)/(opbal + joined)) ab
FROM
  (SELECT pstartdate,
          penddate,
          getopempbal(pstartdate) opbal,
          getempjn(pstartdate,penddate) joined,
          getempres(pstartdate,penddate) resign
   FROM
     (SELECT add_months(:startdate, LEVEL-1) pstartdate,
             add_months(:startdate, LEVEL)-1 penddate
      FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= months_between(:enddate, :startdate) + 1))
ORDER BY to_number(1)
```

Comment: Use nullif to get answer

Comment: The problem - as the error says - is with the divisor, not the divdend. You've got your nullif around the wrong expression.